# Tkinter Tic Tac Toe: Adding a tie condition, binding to keys, stopping the game without closing the canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

With a Tic Tac Toe project almost finished, I am having a few issues regarding binding and adding a tie condition. I'm able to bind functions to  and  and they work normally, but I want them to be bound to R and escape key (reset_game to R and close to escape). I have also tried adding a variable k for the tie condition, but it says that is has not been defined. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
ttt = Tk()
ttt.title("Tic Tac Toe")
w = Canvas(ttt, width = 902, height = 902)
w.configure (bg =  "white")
w.pack()

m = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
size = 300
player = 1


w.create_line(0, 300, 902, 300, fill = "black") 
w.create_line(0, 601, 902, 601, fill = "black")
w.create_line(300, 0, 300, 902, fill = "black")
w.create_line(601, 0, 601, 902, fill = "black")

def on_click(event):
    global m
    global player
    global k
    row = event.y // size
    col = event.x // size
    if m[row][col] == 0:
        cx = col * size + size // 2
        cy = row * size + size // 2
        if player == 1:
            draw_X(cx, cy)
            print ("Player 1, X")
        else:
            draw_O(cx, cy)
            print ("Player 2, O")
        m[row][col] = player
        Win()
        player = 2 if player == 1 else 1
    k = k + 1

def draw_O(x, y):
    radius = size // 3
    w.create_oval(x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius, width=5, tag='cell')

def draw_X(x, y):
    radius = size // 3
    w.create_line(x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius, width=5, tag='cell')
    w.create_line(x+radius, y-radius, x-radius, y+radius, width=5, tag='cell')

def reset_game(event):
    global m
    global player
    w.delete('cell')
    m = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    player = 1
    k = 0

def tie():
    if (k==8):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Tie")

def Win():
    if (m[0][0] == m[0][1] and m[0][0] == m[0][2] and m[0][0]!=0):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Winner is player " + str(m[0][0]))
        ttt.destroy()
        print ("Player", str(m[0][0]), "wins")
    elif (m[0][0] == m[1][0] and m[0][0] == m[2][0] and m[0][0]!=0):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Winner is player " + str(m[0][0]))
        ttt.destroy()
        print ("Player", str(m[0][0]), "wins")
    elif (m[1][0] == m[1][1] and m[1][0] == m[1][2] and m[1][0]!=0):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Winner is player " + str(m[1][0]))
        ttt.destroy()
        print ("Player", str(m[1][0]), "wins")
    elif (m[0][1] == m[1][1] and m[0][1] == m[2][1] and m[0][1]!=0):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Winner is player " + str(m[0][1]))
        ttt.destroy()
        print ("Player", str(m[0][1]), "wins")
    elif (m[0][2] == m[1][2] and m[0][2] == m[2][2] and m[0][2]!=0):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Winner is player " + str(m[0][2]))
        ttt.destroy()
        print ("Player", str(m[0][2]), "wins")
    elif (m[2][0] == m[2][1] and m[2][0] == m[2][2] and m[2][0]!=0):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Winner is player " + str(m[2][0]))
        ttt.destroy()
        print ("Player", str(m[2][0]), "wins")
    elif (m[0][0] == m[1][1] and m[0][0] == m[2][2] and m[0][0]!=0):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Winner is player " + str(m[0][0]))
        ttt.destroy()
        print ("Player", str(m[0][0]), "wins")
    elif (m[0][2] == m[1][1] and m[0][2] == m[2][0] and m[0][2]):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "Winner is player " + str(m[0][2]))
        ttt.destroy()
        print ("Player", str(m[0][2]), "wins")


w.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)

def close(event):
    ttt.destroy()

w.bind('<Button-2>',close)

w.bind('<Button-3>', reset_game)

ttt.mainloop()
```

I also want to stop the game after somebody wins or there's a tie without closing the canvas so I could reset. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: ***"stop the game "*** It's interactive, so what do you want to stop? Read [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: I may have not explained it very well (or not explained at all). If a win condition is met, there's a pop up with the winner. If you close that window, you can still click on the other boxes that are empty. That's why I added the "ttt.destroy()" after every win condition, but I want to change it. Basically, I want to disable the game after every win or tie so I could reset the game using the key, not running the code again.

Comment: ***"want to disable the game"***: You can use the [unbind-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.unbind-method) to make `funcid = w.bind('<Button-1>', ...` inactive.

Comment: Alright, thanks! That worked. Now there's only the other 2 issues I have yet to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have added global variable `k` as the number of turns played, `player` can be determined by value of `k` so it can be removed from the global variables.

You need to declare global variable `k`:

```
m = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
size = 300
k = 0
```

Also you can simplify/modify the function `Win` to accept the `row` and `col` as arguments and return whether there is winner:

```
 def Win(row, col):
    # check horizontal
    if m[row][0] == m[row][1] == m[row][2]:
        return m[row][col]
    # check vertical
    if m[0][col] == m[1][col] == m[2][col]:
        return m[row][col]
    # check diagonals
    cell = (row, col)
    if cell in ((0,0), (1,1), (2,2)) and m[0][0] == m[1][1] == m[2][2]:
        return m[row][col]
    if cell in ((2,0), (1,1), (0,2)) and m[2][0] == m[1][1] == m[0][2]:
        return m[row][col]
    # no winner, returns None
    return None
```

Then modify `on_click` function:

```
def on_click(event):
    global m
    global k
    row = event.y // size
    col = event.x // size
    if m[row][col] == 0:
        cx = col * size + size // 2
        cy = row * size + size // 2
        # determine current player
        player = 1 + k % 2
        if player == 1:
            draw_X(cx, cy)
            print("Player 1, X")
        else:
            draw_O(cx, cy)
            print("Player 2, O")
        m[row][col] = player
        k += 1
        # only need to check winner after 5 turns
        if k >= 5:
            winner = Win(row, col)
            msg = None
            if winner:
                msg = "Winner is player {}: {}".format(player, 'X' if player == 1 else 'O')
            elif k == 9:
                msg = "Tie game"
            if msg:
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", msg)
                reset_game()
```

For the keys binding:

```
w.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: ttt.destroy())
w.bind('R', reset_game)
w.bind('r', reset_game)
w.focus_set()   # Canvas need to get the focus in order to get the keyboard events
```